# Maintain hover state (jQuery)

Tags: jquery, drop-down-menu, menu, hover

HTML:

```
<ul class="dropdown">
    <li><a href="#">Item 1</a></li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <div class="submenu">something</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

jQuery:

```
    $j("ul.dropdown li").hover(function () {
        $j(this).addClass("hover");
        $j('div.submenu', this).css('visibility', 'visible');
    }, function () {
        $j(this).removeClass("hover");
        $j('div.submenu', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

... the menu works fine, but when the `div.submenu` is shown and I move the cursor to it, the link that opened this submenu loses its 'hover' class, how do I maintain hover state on both the link and the submenu when they're open?

I tried this, but its not working:

```
$j("ul.dropdown li").hover(function () {
        $j(this).addClass("hover");
        $j('div.submenu', this).css('visibility', 'visible').hover(function () {
                $j(this).prev('a').addClass('hover');
            }, function () {
                $j(this).prev('a').removeClass('hover');
            });    
    }, function () {
        $j(this).removeClass("hover");
        $j('div.submenu', this).css('visibility', 'hidden');
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may need to consider the submenu div also part of jQuery elements, while attaching hover effect to. May be sth like this:

```
$('ul.dropdown li').each(function() {
    var self = $(this),
        menu = $(this).find('div.submenu'),
        el = menu.add(this);
    el.hover(function() {
            self.addClass("hover");
    menu.css("visibility", "visible");
    }, function() {
            self.removeClass("hover");
        menu.css("visibility", "hidden");
    });
});
```

Comment: Thanks, but its still the same, the parent link returns to normal when I move to the sub-menu.

Comment: have another class "active", which u can add to the <li> tag while making menu visible and remove when hiding it. This "active" shall have same css effect on header el as "hover"

Answer (score 1):

You cannot maintain the hover state on an element that you don't hover :) Try putting the `div.submenu` inside the `ul.dropdown li`, if it is possible. Another solution is to stop relying on `hover()` and use another way of manipulating your classes. Don't use the `hover()` to toggle classes, use some function to do it and call it when you need it.

Comment: I'm assuming div.submenu *is* in the li. The selector looks like it's looking for .submenu in 'this' (the comma is outside of, not within, the quotes).

Comment: Well, yes, we need to see his HTML code. And some of the CSS, because giving `div.submenu` some absolute positioning can ruin hover, too.

Comment: What I was thinking maybe add a condition that if hover on submenu, addclass hover to parent?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, js menus are more trouble than they're worth. There's a perfectly workable [CSS solution](http://htmldog.com/articles/suckerfish/dropdowns/) if you don't want any fancy fadein or rolldown effects.

But! This might have to do with CSS anyway. I think people are overthinking it. All you really want is for your link to still look hovered over--your display's fine. Okay. You can do this with CSS and jQuery:

```
ul.dropdown li:hover a,
ul.dropdown li.hover a {
/* how your link should look */
}
```

Now, if you have that style (`.hover` is important) there already, your submenu should be disappearing on hover, too, so something else is afoot.

Comment: Also, why not .hide() and .show() instead of declaring the CSS? visible/hidden reserve space, is that why?